# Can't initialize PDA cause of seed constraint, even though seeds are correct

Tags: pda, account, seed

I am trying to create a PDA with variable seeds like this

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(i: u8)]

pub struct SendRequest<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut,seeds= ["client".as_ref(), owner.key().as_ref()],bump)]
    pub client: AccountLoader<'info, Client>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = owner,
        space = 200,
        seeds= ["request".as_ref(),owner.key().as_ref(),client.key().as_ref(),&[i]],
        bump
    )]
    pub request: AccountLoader<'info, RequestData>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

i'm using this account here

```
 pub fn send_request(ctx: Context<SendRequest>, request: Request, i: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let s = request.name();

        let name = String::from_utf8(s.to_vec()).unwrap();
        if validate_name(&name.as_bytes()) == false {
            return err!(AgentError::InvalidName);
        }
        let req = &mut ctx.accounts.request.load_init()?;
        req.requester = ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info().key();
        req.request = request;
        Ok(())
    }
```

and i am finding this seed by doing this

```
const request = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from("request"),
        program.provider.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        client.toBuffer(),
        //@ts-ignore
        [1]
      ],
      program.programId
    )[0];
```

Apparently this works for `[0]` but does not work for anything else like `[1]` or so

still i'm getting seed constraint violated error if i try in `solana playground` and `signer's privillage escalated` if i try doing anchor test.

Comment: apparently this works for `[0]`, but not for `[1]` or anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accepting two arguments in send_request function:
`request: Request, i: u8`

But only mentioned one argument in the instruction: `#[instruction(i: u8)]`

Replace the above with `#[instruction(request: Request, i: u8)]` and your program will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace #[instruction(i: u8)] with **#[instruction(request: Request, i: u8)]** or simply change **send_request function** parameters arrangement to **i: u8, request: Request**

Answer (score 0):

Change `[request_id]` to `&request_id.to_le_bytes()`

Here is a reference:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod pda {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, id: u8) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(id: u8)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + 8,
        seeds= ["seed".as_ref(), signer.key().as_ref(), &id.to_le_bytes()],
        bump
    )]
    pub pda: Account<'info, Data>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Data {
    pub data: u64,
}
```

Also change `[1]` to `Buffer.from([1])`

Here is a reference:

```
describe("pda", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env())

  const program = anchor.workspace.Pda as Program<Pda>

  const PDA = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [
      Buffer.from("seed"),
      program.provider.publicKey.toBuffer(),
      Buffer.from([1]),
      ,
    ],
    program.programId
  )[0]

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const tx = await program.methods.initialize(1).accounts({ pda: PDA }).rpc()
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx)
  })
})
```

Comment: Still the same error, `5kqCiAbbtQfpvygEfzZqZyQDbYLj89Jgt2LVRKQdh3nS's signer privilege escalated`

Comment: Can you share the instruction the pda is used in? which account is that public key for?

Comment: just edited the question.